# Partition error when reinstall ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I have two physical drives with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 8.1. Both have EFI partitions. I'm trying to reinstall Ubuntu from a live USB. If I have both drives connected I have an error that two file systems have identical mount points and I can't do anything with that. If I disconnect the drive with Windows, I have another error:

```
The partition table format in use on your disks normally requires you to create a separate partition for boot loader code. This partition should be marked for use as an "EFI boot partition" and should be at least 35 MB in size. Note that this is not the same as a partition mounted on /boot.

If you do not go back to the partitioning menu and correct this error, bootloader installation may fail later, although it may still be possible to install the bootloader to a partition.
```

My Gigabyte motherboard has UEFI dualbios. I selected no CSM support, Other OS and UEFI OpROM. I have no options for the secure boot so I don't know whether it's enabled or not.

How can I deal with this error?

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely about the [EFI System Partion (ESP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition). The installer should normally take care of all that for you if you let it automatically partition the disk. I would recommend to wipe out the partition table and let the installer do its job. E.g., disconnect the windows drive so you don't lose it, then `wipefs -a /dev/sda`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I'm trying to reinstall ubuntu in data-safe mode. If it isn't possible I will wipe data and install it.